# Is there a way to reference group variables when importing in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In my Ansible scripts, is there a way to reference a path variable when importing a playbook?

I have set up some variables with the path to different files in my Ansible file hierarchy that I would like to reference when importing and including playbook and variable files.  The path variables are defined in a file in the group_vars/all/ directory so they are loaded automatically.

When I try to import a playbook and reference one of my path variables, I get an error that the variable is not defined.

Here's an example.  I created a simple playbook file that I call include.yml:

```
---
- name: Include playbook
  import_playbook: "{{ base_dir }}/foo.yml"
```

The playbook imports another playbook called foo.yml in a directory defined in the variable, base_dir.

Here is foo.yml:

```
---
- name:
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Check that group_vars/all variable loaded
      debug:
        var: test_dir
```

In the group_vars/all/ directory, I define base_dir and test_dir in a file called dirs.yml:

```
base_dir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
test_dir: "{{ base_dir }}/foo"
```

When I run:

```
ansible-playbook include.yml
```

I expect that Ansible will import and run foo.yml, which prints the value of the test_dir variable which references base_dir.

Instead, I get the error:

```
ERROR! 'base_dir' is undefined
```

If I run:

```
ansible-playbook include.yml --extra-vars base_dir="."
```

then it runs as expected.

It appears that the import occurs before the group_vars variables are loaded.

If true, this is inconvenient because I would like to define my file paths in global variables that can be referenced by multiple playbooks, instead of hardcoding them in all of my playbooks.  Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: "I would like to define my file paths in global variables that can be referenced by multiple playbooks, instead of hardcoding them in all of my playbooks. Is there a way around this issue?

A: It's a rational expectation that group_vars/all might have been loaded before a playbook is imported. But neither playbook nor inventory related group_vars/all works this way. There are closed issues on this topic (`locked and limited conversation to collaborators on Apr 27`) for example [playbook_vars_root doesn't work for playbook imports #34239](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34239).

There is no workaround. The [scope](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables) of such variables is the play. *goup_vars* can't be loaded before the *hosts* is known from the play.

FWIW. An option of running playbooks in a systemic and flexible way is [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner). See [Runner Input Directory Hierarchy](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-input-directory-hierarchy) and [Running Playbooks](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/standalone.html#running-playbooks).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation makes sense.  I'll have to take a look at ansible-runner to see if that gets me around the issue.